# The Will of Rabbi Judah Ha'chassid

Tags: gentiles, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Is there a discussion about non-Jewish influence on the Sefer Hassidim or the will of Rabbi Yehuda Hachassid?

Comment: This is very interesting. The concepts in the Will and in a great part of the sefer chasidim are hidden. The cultural background of chachme Sfarad is well known, but the cultural background of Baale Hatosfot is less known. In the book, many French words are used.

Comment: Mark, I suggest modifying the question to instead seek for a source (an article or the like) that may point you in the right direction. For example, you can ask, "Did anyone ever publish a study sourcing the statements in the Will of Rabbi Judah the Hasid, and if yes where could I find it?"

Comment: @Mark A. please check if my edit is close to your question